# Error appending variable in os.system command - Python windows

Tags: python

Hi is there something wrong with this code

```
    currentdirectory = os.getcwd()
    processfile=currentdirectory+"\ClientProcessList.txt"
    print processfile
    os.system('WMIC /OUTPUT: %s PROCESS get Caption,Commandline,Processid') % processfile
```

error :

`os.system('WMIC /OUTPUT: %s PROCESS get Caption,Commandline,Processid') % pr
    ocessfile
    TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'int' and 'str'`

I even tried this :

`os.system('WMIC /OUTPUT: '+processfile+' PROCESS get Caption,Commandline,Processid')`

error:

`Invalid Global Switch.`

Answer (score 0):

What happens is that the syntax to format a string is:

```
"some string %s" % "the string"
```

but you have parentheses `()` before the `%`:

```
some_function("some string %s") % "the string"   # this will try to apply 
                                                 # the % operator to the value
                                                 # returned by the function.
```

Since you want to apply the format to the *string* that you are passing as argument, it should be:

```
some_function("some string %s " % "the string")
```

In your case:

```
os.system('WMIC /OUTPUT: %s PROCESS get Caption,Commandline,Processid' % processfile)
```

Comment: Hi, i did try that command but got "Invalis global switch" error, however since i want to create the file in current directory i just put the file name intead of full path.. works fine.. Thanks you